# TableView rows dissapear when tapped

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, icarousel

I have a table view embedded in an [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) item and firstly I can't seem to set the view frame whether it's in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` but also when I tap the Tableview all the cells disappear. I have created the Tableview in its own ViewController as each carousel item will need editing buttons for the Tableviews they contain. If I don't put the Tableview in its own view controller the cells remain but I get an index out of range when scrolling a lot of views and I can't add editing buttons. I've run out of ideas and would love some pointers or tips.

```
class BillSplitterTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        var splitter: BillSplitter?
        var tableView: UITableView!
        var viewFrame: CGRect?

        init(frame: CGRect, splitter: BillSplitter) {
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

            self.splitter = splitter
            self.viewFrame = frame
        }
        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:)")
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let subView = UIView(frame: viewFrame!)

            view.backgroundColor = .clear

            tableView = UITableView(frame: view.frame)
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.frame = subView.frame
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 35

            let tableViewBackground = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: splitter?.image as! Data, scale:1.0))
            tableViewBackground.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            tableViewBackground.frame = tableView.frame

            tableView.backgroundView = tableViewBackground

            subView.addSubview(tableView)
            view.addSubview(subView)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if (splitter?.items?.count)! > 0 {
                return (splitter!.items?.count)!
            } else {
                TableViewHelper.EmptyMessage("\(splitter?.name!) has no items to pay for.", tableView: tableView)
                return 0
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            tableView.register(SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "splitterCarouselItemTableViewCell")
            let cell: SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "splitterCarouselItemTableViewCell") as! SplitterCarouselItemTableViewCell
            let item = (splitter?.items?.allObjects as! [Item])[indexPath.row]
            let count = item.billSplitters?.count

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xe9edef).withAlphaComponent(0.5)

            if count! > 1 {
                cell.name!.text = "\(item.name!)\nsplit \(count!) ways"
                cell.price!.text = "£\(Double(item.price)/Double(count!))"

            } else {
                cell.name!.text = item.name!
                cell.price!.text = "£\(item.price)"
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

the carousel viewcontroller:

```
 func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    return allBillSplitters.count
}


func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let splitter = allBillSplitters[index]

    carouselIndex = index

    let splitterView = SplitterCarouselItemView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    let viewWidth = Int(splitterView.frame.width)

    let nameLabel = SplitterCarouselItemNameLabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: 30))
    let emailLabel = SplitterCarouselItemEmailLabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: viewWidth, height: 20))
    let addItemButton = SplitterCarouselItemButton(frame: CGRect(x: viewWidth - 45, y: 50, width: 35, height: 35), addsItem: true)
    let deleteItemButton = SplitterCarouselItemButton(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: 35, height: 35), addsItem: false)

    let itemHeight = Int(splitterView.frame.height)
    let payTotalButton = SplitterCarouselItemPayButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: itemHeight - 35, width: viewWidth + 1, height: 35))

    let tableViewHeight = Int(height - 130)
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 85, width: viewWidth, height: tableViewHeight)

    let tableView = BillSplitterTableView(frame: frame, splitter: splitter)

    splitterView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    splitterView.addSubview(emailLabel)
    splitterView.addSubview(addItemButton)
    splitterView.addSubview(deleteItemButton)
    splitterView.addSubview(tableView.view)
    splitterView.addSubview(payTotalButton)

    nameLabel.text = "\(allBillSplitters[index].name!)"
    emailLabel.text = "\(allBillSplitters[index].email!)"
    payTotalButton.setTitle("Pay £\(allBillSplitters[index].total)", for: .normal)

    return splitterView
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if allBillSplitters.count > 2 {
        switch option {
        case .spacing:
            return value * 1.05
        case .fadeMin:
            return 0.0
        case .fadeMinAlpha:
            return 0.3
        case .fadeMax:
            return 0.0
        default:
            return value
        }
    }
    return value
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I did but i cant remember how, the project has evolved a lot since then. Links to the files in my github here if that helps: https://github.com/wrumble/Splitter/blob/0e0ef9fd0c6d1e0a9b7297da735685e909391d59/Splitter/CarouselSplitterTableView.swift https://github.com/wrumble/Splitter/blob/0e0ef9fd0c6d1e0a9b7297da735685e909391d59/Splitter/BillSplittersViewController.swift